# removing "#text" while parsing xml and displaying node value

Tags: c#, xml

I have a program to display the node name and value like this

```
public void findAllNodes(XmlNode node)
{
    Console.Write("{0}:", node.Name);

    Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}"," ");
    foreach (XmlNode n in node.ChildNodes)
        findAllNodes(n);
}
```

using this xml:

```
<application_data>
    <applicant_data type="primary"> 
        <first_name>VINNY</first_name> 
        <mi></mi> 
        <last_name>SSILVERLACE</last_name> 
        <ssn>666279999</ssn> 
        <dob>1973-06-27</dob> 
        <address type="current">
            <po_box_no></po_box_no> 
            <roural_route></roural_route> 
            <street_no>7690</street_no> 
            <street_name>KETTLEDRUMS</street_name> 
            <apt_no></apt_no> 
            <city>MILILANI TOWN</city> 
            <state>HI</state> 
            <zip_code>96789</zip_code> 
        </address>
    </applicant_data>
</application_data>
```

But for this code, while displaying the node values, it diplays like this

```
#text:("node value").
```

Can you suggest some way to delete "#text" from the node value?

Comment: What does your xml look like?

Comment: <application_data>
    <applicant_data type="primary">
      <first_name>VINNY</first_name>
      <mi></mi>
      <last_name>SSILVERLACE</last_name>
      <ssn>666270015</ssn>
      <dob>1973-06-27</dob>
      <address type="current">
        <po_box_no></po_box_no>
        <roural_route></roural_route>
        <street_no>7690</street_no>
        <street_name>KETTLEDRUMS</street_name>
        <apt_no></apt_no>
        <city>MILILANI TOWN</city>
        <state>HI</state>
        <zip_code>96789</zip_code>
      </address></applicant_data></application_data>

Comment: What version of .net are you using? I'd recommend `Linq-To-Xml` if 3.5 (I believe) or better.

Comment: I am using version 4.0

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with your xml, but with your `node.Name` statement.

If you look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.name.aspx) you will see that, `node.Name` will print `#text` for text nodes every time. I'm not familiar enough with XmlNode to tell you how to get the tag name as you appear to be wanting.  You could try Linq-To-Xml as someone commented.

Example:

```
public void findAllNodes(XElement node)
{
    Console.Write("{0}:", node.Name.ToString());

    Console.WriteLine(node.Value);
    Console.WriteLine("{0}"," ");
    foreach (XElement n in node.Elements())
        findAllNodes(n);
}

findAllNodes(XElement.Load(file));
```

Comment: Thank you for making me know that the problem is with node.name instead of node.value. But still this problem persists. and I did not understand when you told to use Linq-To-Xml. What is that? is that a class? can you suggest a way out?

Comment: @user3680601 Linq-To-Xml is the new XML standard that came out with .Net 3.0 for accessing individual nodes. It is light and fast.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void RecurseXmlDocument(XmlNode root)
{
    if (root is XmlElement)
    {
        Console.Write("\n" + root.Name + ": ");
        if (root.HasChildNodes) RecurseXmlDocument(root.FirstChild);
        if (root.NextSibling != null) RecurseXmlDocument(root.NextSibling);
    }
    else if (root is XmlText)
    {
        Console.Write(((XmlText)root).Value);
    }
    else if (root is XmlComment)
    {
        Console.Write(root.Value);
        if (root.HasChildNodes) RecurseXmlDocument(root.FirstChild);
        if (root.NextSibling != null) RecurseXmlDocument(root.NextSibling);
    }
}
```

I modified [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/CSharp/0540__XML/LoopThroughXmlDocumentRecursively.htm) according to your needs and it works just fine now. You're going to have to call it like this:

```
public static void Main()
{
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.Load("File.xml");
    RecurseXmlDocument((XmlNode)document.DocumentElement);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```